# Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'. when trying to use any firebase app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to create a web app that depends on firebase apps. The app runs if no firebase dependencies are added. Once I add the apps the app fails to build and run with this error:

```
lib\main.dart:1
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:44:14: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    getPath: allowInterop(strategy.getPath),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:45:15: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    getState: allowInterop(strategy.getState),
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:46:26: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.

    addPopStateListener: allowInterop(strategy.addPopStateListener),
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:47:25: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    prepareExternalUrl: allowInterop(strategy.prepareExternalUrl),
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:48:16: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    pushState: allowInterop(strategy.pushState),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:49:19: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    replaceState: allowInterop(strategy.replaceState),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:50:9: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    go: allowInterop(strategy.go),
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.1.0/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:85:12: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    return allowInterop(dartObject);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.1.0/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:120:27: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
  return PromiseJsImpl<S>(allowInterop((
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I was following the web installation guide found here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web/